# Bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal

Estou montando um aplicativo mobile usando asp.net (aspx) e bootstrap modal.
O objetivo desta modal é preencher uma label com a informação contida no atributo "data-marcacao" do href que aciona esta modal. Quando a modal é acionada na 1a tentativa a label não está sendo preenchida. A label está sendo preenchida somente na 2a tentativa de abertura da modal após o myButton "Sim" ter sido clicado na 1a tentativa.

```
//acionamento
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-marcacao="frase qualquer">

//modal
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblModalMarcacao" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn btn-success btn-md" id="myButton">Sim</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-md" data-dismiss="modal">Não</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

//script
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#myModal').modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false });
            $('#myModal').modal('toggle');
            $('#myModal').modal('handleUpdate');

            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("a").on("click", function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $('#lblModalMarcacao').text('Marcação: ' + $(this).attr("data-marcacao"));
                });
            });
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Mas qual problema exatamente você está tendo?

Comment: A label está sendo preenchida somente após a modal ter sido aberta uma primeira vez e o Button "Sim" ter sido clicado, ou seja, a label está sendo preenchida somente quando a modal é acionada na 2a tentativa de abertura. Na primeira tentativa de abertura a label não está sendo preenchida.

Comment: Descobri o problema. Estava usando um componente ScriptManager no body. Tirei o componente ScriptManager e o problema acabou.

Comment: Ótimo! parabéns, se quiser você mesmo pode postar aqui a solução para ajudar caso outra pessoa tenha o mesmo problema.

Answer (score 0):

Descobri o problema. Estava usando um componente ScriptManager no body. Tirei o componente ScriptManager e o problema acabou.